# Connection string for code first mode with mysql

Tags: entity-framework

I am working on a project that gets connection strings for Entity Framework from environment variables, like this:

```
public class SomeTests {
    [Fact]
    public async void TestSomething() {
        string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APP_CONN_STR");
        var appContextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDataContext>();
        appContextOptionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString); // hardcoded mysql

        AppDataContext context = new AppDataContext(appContextOptionsBuilder.Options);

        Assert.Equal(context.Country.Count(), 0);
    }
}
....

public partial class AppDataContext : DbContext, IAppDataContext
{
    public AppDataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }

    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("country");
            ...
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

The code above is a bootstrapper code for some automated integration testing. Historically every developer is using the same old database instance on the network without a problem. I am trying to make these tests run in an isolated environment, so I have set up an empty new mysql database (using docker to make it reproducible), and let Entity Framework to populate it with a schema.

The problem is, when I create an empty database in this mysql instance and give a connection string to that database, then I am getting table not found errors:

```
connection str: Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=app_mysql_db;Uid=root;Pwd=****;

error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : Table 'app_mysql_db.country' doesn't exist
```

I found out that EF will not create tables in existing databases, it will only populate a database with tables if EF itself created it. This is the default behavior of EF.

So I tried to remove the database name from the connection string:

```
connection str: Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Uid=root;Pwd=****;

error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : No database selected
```

So how do I let Entity Framework in Code First mode to create my tables?

Comment: Presumably the person who set the project up used Database First and not Code First, can't you just copy the database to the server and work on the copy?

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush thanks, if there is no better option then I would do that, but that has negative implications, like having to update the "database setup script" everytime the datamodel changes. My vision is having local dockerized databases to fire up and getting initialized just for the tests.

Comment: If you're going to have different instances of a DB First database it's going to be a pain to administer. It might be worth making your own Code First version of it. Perhaps if your app is going to use both versions you can put an abstraction layer between the database layer to get round this.